# scrollfunction for canvas if canvas too big

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the visualisation arborjs and I am trying to implement the zoom-function. This isn't included in the visualisation itself so I had to try some different approches.

I can't use the html5 canvasfunction `.scale` because with this the positions given by the visualisation don't match the real positions anymore.
For the moment I just increase the height and width of the canvas to zoom in. This doesn't give any problems with the positioningproblem, but I can't scroll in the canvas.

The only problem that I have to solve is the scrollfunction to make this work. So my question is: can I add scrollbars to the canvas when the canvas becomes too big.
Initially the canvas has width 100% and height 100%, so no scrollbars are needed, but when I enlarge this I need those scrollbars.

I tried the css-style overflow:scroll for both the canvas and the surrounding div, but no results.

Here is the relevant code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="explore_area">
    <canvas class="explore_area" id="viewport">
    </canvas>   
</div>
```

**javascript:**

```
zoom: function(){
            var canvas = document.getElementById("viewport");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            sys.screenSize((canvas.width*1.5), (canvas.height*1.5));
        }
```

**css:**

```
div.explore_area {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

canvas.explore_area{
    float:left;
    height:550px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the width and height of canvas using css is not a good idea. To achieve what you required you should not give width and height of canvas in css. Even if you change the dimension css will reset it.

so first you need to give dimension like this

```
<canvas class="explore_area" id="viewport" width="400" height="300">
```

css for container

```
div.explore_area {
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

see the demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/diode/sHbKD/22/ ( not using arborjs)

Comment: when you remove the overflow:auto from you demo, it works so thank you for that.
in my application it does not work. The only thing that is different with your example is the assignment of the width and height: for this I use the arborfunction .screenSize like this:

var canvas = document.getElementById("viewport");
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   sys.screenSize((canvas.width*1.5), (canvas.height*1.5));

because of the positioning problem

Comment: Hope you have removed the css for canvas. Give css only for the container div.

Comment: I did, this is the contents of the css-file for the moment:

div.explore_area {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
}

canvas.explore_area{
}

Comment: does sys.screenSize resize the canvas ? What is the result now ?

Comment: it changes the values to calculate the positions of the nodes with, but doesn't do anything with the canvas itself, so when I combined the sys.screenSize() with canvas.width = and canvas.height it worked!
so thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

> I can't use the html5 canvasfunction .scale because with this the positions given by the visualisation don't match the real positions anymore.

What do you mean by that ?? If you want to draw an image same place, but zoomed, you can do :

```
ctx.save();
ctx.scale(ratio, ratio);
ctx.drawImage(myImage, x/ratio, y/ratio ) ;
ctx.restore();
```

Or if you want to zoom from the middle of the image :

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(x + myImage.width/2, y + myImage.height/2 );
ctx.scale(ratio, ratio);
ctx.drawImage(myImage, - myImage.width/(2*ratio), - myImage.width/(2*ratio) ) ;
ctx.restore();
```

Rq : For clarity, i did not use Math.floor() on drawImage coordinates, but do it to save draw time in
case your ratio (or your coordinates) are not integer.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to append a `<div>(position:absolute)` covering the canvas. It's not good if canvas has interactive.